# Curve25519 implementation for javascript?

Tags: javascript, encryption, public-key-encryption

Is there a curve25519 implementation for javascript available?

It needs to be able to both sign and verify. Only thing I've found just signs.

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular programming problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Curve25519](http://cr.yp.to/ecdh.html) implements Diffie-Hellman key exchange; it doesn't sign or verify anything, it only generates a shared key via scalar multiplication. If you're looking for signatures, use [Ed25519](http://ed25519.cr.yp.to/), which is an implementation of Schnorr signature algorithm on the same elliptic curve.

Here are links to some JavaScript implementations of both Curve25519 and Ed25519:

- http://www.flownet.com/ron/code/ (GPL license)
- https://github.com/tonyg/js-nacl (compiled with Emscripten)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this (https://github.com/rev22/curve255js) implementation